# Repositioning images in a gallery based on the current image

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on extending the functionality of a photo gallery by adding a thumbnail display, I have multiple if statements set up to adjust the position of the thumbnails. Obviously this is not ideal, I'm trying to put my head around how to use a for loop to iterate the width multiplier and curSlide position.

Ideally I would like the curSlide to increment after every 5 slide and the thumbGalwidth*i to increment as well.

```
var thumbGalwidth = 795;

if(currSlide < 6) {
jQuery('#view-all-container').css('margin-left', '-' + thumbGalwidth*0 + 'px');
}
if(currSlide >= 6) {
jQuery('#view-all-container').css('margin-left', '-' + thumbGalwidth*1 + 'px');
}
if (currSlide >= 11) {
jQuery('#view-all-container').css('margin-left', '-' + thumbGalwidth*2 + 'px');
}
if (currSlide >= 16) {
jQuery('#view-all-container').css('margin-left', '-' + thumbGalwidth*3 +     'px');
}
if (currSlide >= 21) {
jQuery('#view-all-container').css('margin-left', '-' + thumbGalwidth*4 +    'px');
}
if (currSlide >= 26) {
jQuery('#view-all-container').css('margin-left', '-' + thumbGalwidth*5 +    'px');
}
```

Comment: How does `curSlide` change over time in this code? It looks quite fixed, and I suspect you omitted the looping code calling this function. Please provide enough context to advise you intelligently.

Comment: Be wary with accepting answers so quickly.  It could discourage future reviews from being written.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you have nice, predictable ranges, you don't need a loop at all. Just do a little math.

```
var thumbGalwidth = 795;

var n = Math.floor(((currSlide || 1)-1) / 5);

jQuery('#view-all-container').css('margin-left', '-' + thumbGalwidth*n + 'px');
```

---

If the largest `n` should be `5`, then change the assignment to this:

```
var n = Math.min(5, Math.floor(((currSlide || 1)-1) / 5));
```